# Command flushright and \emph not recognised

Tags: alignment

I am writing my thesis and I would like to define the command `\dedicationpage` in my class.

I have done the following in my .cls file.

```
\newcommand\dedicationpage[1][]{
\ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{
    \cleardoublepage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \null
    \cleardoublepage
}{
    \cleardoublepage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \null
    \vspace{\stretch{1}}
    %
    \begin{flushright}
        \emph{#1}
    \end{flushright}
    %
    \vspace{\stretch{3}}
    \null
    %
    \cleardoublepage
    }%
}
```

However, in my tex file I write

```
\dedicationpage{To Martino,\\
            for the hope. \\
            To Gabri and Betta, \\
            for the bravery.}
```

and what I get is the image I attach. [image]

which is not right aligned nor emphasised.

Comment: I'd use `\itshape` within you local definition.

Comment: Thanks. It works to make it italic, but still I don't understand why latex doesn't see the `\emph{}` command nor the `\flushright` one

Comment: You're defining `\dedicationpage` with an optional argument, but use it with braces: `\dedicationpage[To Martino,...]`

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be no (good?!) reason for making the single argument of `\dedicationpage` *optional*. If you change the line

```
\newcommand\dedicationpage[1][]{
```

to

```
\newcommand\dedicationpage[1]{%
```

i.e., if you make the argument *mandatory*, you can then write

```
\dedicationpage{To Martino,\\
            for the hope. \\
            To Gabri and Betta, \\
            for the bravery.}
```

and get exactly what you'd expect. If you want the dedication page to be blank, just write `\dedicationpage{}` or `\dedicationpage{\null}`.

Alternatively, if for some reason you wish to keep the optional-argument setup, just accept @egreg's advice and write

```
\dedicationpage[To Martino,\\
            for the hope. \\
            To Gabri and Betta, \\
            for the bravery.]
```

i.e., encase the argument in square brackets, not curly braces.